# Django Form - Pass Extra Arguments (Dynamic Form Creation)

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I am trying to pass extra parameters (not provided by the Forms) in customize my template

In this case I am passing an icon font.

```
class AddForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      *passing some args*
       self.fields[field_key] = forms.CharField(**field_args)
       self.fields[field_key].icon = 'fa-font'
```

```
template.html
{% for field in form%}
    {{field.icon}}
    {{field}}
{% endfor %}
```

When I render the form to to the view, no icon is printed out.

How can I pass extra parameters to a form field?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah sure bcs when you use constructor **init** in form you can change only values of your field like:

```
just_value = models.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=YourModel.objects.none())
```

And then you can pass only .queryest in **init**

```
self.fields['just_value'].queryset = YourModel.objects.filter(something_there)
```

Im not sure about icons but you can style your field by add widget attrs:

```
just_value = models.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=YourModel.objects.none(),
        widget=attrs{'class':'form-class')
```

I would like to recommend you package 'django-widget-tweaks` and render every of your fieild with `{% render_field %}`

Comment: thank you so much, I am using render_field from 'django-widget-tweaks` , for my dynamic form but I still need to pass in some custom properties (i.e. icons) which I believe cannot accomplish what I am trying to do (as these properties need to be passed from my forms.Form and then decide on how to render them.)

Comment: did you mean that I could pass any attrs to the widget? or I can only pass certain allowed params?

Comment: No, not any attrs check this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/widgets/

Comment: You can actually read about django-crispy-forms they can solve your problem but you  cant put icon in your form.py file

Comment: Or you just need to use html + css bcs django its a backend framework and you cant do a lot with frontend in him